# Python Crash Course (2e.) problem with accessing the value associated with a key

Tags: python

I'm reading through Python Crash Course (2e.) and I was stuck with an example on Page 102 about accessing the value associated with a key.

The code I have is as follows:

```
favorite_languages = {
    'jen': 'python',
    'sarah': 'c',
    'edward': 'ruby',
    'phil': 'python',
    }

friends = ['phil', 'sarah']
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(f"Hi {name.title()}")

if name in friends:
    language = favorite_languages[name].title()
    print(f"\t{name.title()}, I see you love {language}!")
```

If I understand correctly, the outcome should include something like this:
****"Hi Phil
Phil, I see you love Python!
Hi Sarah
Sarah, I see you love C!"****

However, I only see the sentence for Paul.
Could someone help me with the matter?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to indent the if statement block

Comment: the current output is not as you stated. @coderoftheday's solution does not give the required output. Please create a working reproducible and state its output and exact desired output

Comment: It does...... @Gulzar

Comment: @coderoftheday Indeed, the indent works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The  **for**  loop has to be exhausted before the compiler reaches the **if** statement. So you should see something like this as the output:

```
Hi Jen
Hi Sarah
Hi Edward
Hi Phil
    Phil, I see you love Python!
```

First it goes through the for loop printing all the names/keys in the dictionary.

```
for name in favorite_languages.keys():
    print(f"Hi {name.title()}")
```

After printing the keys, it goes to the if statement with the last stored variable 'name' 's value which is 'Phil'.

It checks is this name value is there in the list 'friends' and if so it executes the if statement.

PS : If you don't understand any tutorial example  write it up in any editor, use print statements anywhere you feel a doubt which helps you to understand what's happening there! **Happy Learning ;)**

Comment: @OP also check out python tutor: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit